# Padé Approximation of $\sin(x)$ using Matlab

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, pade-approximation

How to determine Padé approximation of degree $6$ for $f(x)=\sin x$, and 
compare the results at $x_i = 0.2i$ for $i = 0,1,2,3,4,5$, with $f(x)$ and with its sixth Maclaurin
polynomial with $n=2$ and $m=4$ ...USING MATLAB?

Comment: Does $(m,n)=(4,2)$ mean that the denominator is quadratic? How do you encode polynomials? Did you find the function for polynomial division? Do you know the extended Euclidean algorithm? What sources for the Padé table computation have you found?

Comment: See the answer by Claude Leibovici to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2196371

Comment: I am familiar with how to find the pade approximation using taylor by hand, I just dont know how to do the comparison in matlab as it asks in the question.

Comment: I was referring to the [algorithm I wrote into wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant#Computation) and also in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2196435/115115) to the above linked question.